# problem in appending row to the dataframe

Tags: python, plc, twincat

I am a beginner level pyADS user and I have to record values from PLC using pyADS. problem is that python program is getting the values but is unable to append new data into the data frame. program exits the execution and if it is re: run then the initially stored value gets overwritten. I want to record the values and append the values to the data frame when all the values are available.

Following is the code I tried(WRITTEN IN pycharm IDE) :

```
import pyads                    # importing pyads library that is used to communicate with the PLC
from Connection_to_plc import * # importing the connection_to_plc which contains addresses of PLCs attached
import pandas as pd             
import time                     # recommended for PLC codes
S6.open()                       # Opening connection with the PLC
S6.write_by_name("GS1.HMI_Reset", True) # Reseting the PLC
S6.write_by_name("GS1.Integrate", True) # Using PLC in integrate mode
DF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['JOB_NO', 'JOB_ID', 'ST_M5']) # Dataframe's columns NAME
while  True:                                                    # While true because the values in following variables will be accessed as long as the PLC is working
    Cond = S6.read_by_name('CNY.SEN2', pyads.PLCTYPE_BOOL)      # BOOl variable which is trigger event if it is true then the row should be appended into DATAFRAME
    JobNo = S6.read_by_name('AutoCur_Prog.count', pyads.PLCTYPE_INT)        # simple counter value from PLC
    JobID = (S6.read_by_name('AutoCur_Prog.count', pyads.PLCTYPE_INT))*100  # selfmade data
    STm5 = S6.read_by_name('GS1.SetupTime', pyads.PLCTYPE_LREAL)            # again data from PLC
    if JobNo is not None and JobID is not None and STm5 is not None and JobNo != 0 and JobID != 0 and STm5 != 0: #if the values of variable is not none or not 0 then it should be added
        new_row = {'JOB_NO': JobNo, 'JOB_ID':JobID, 'ST_M5': STm5 }
        DF = pd.concat([DF, pd.DataFrame([new_row])], ignore_index= True)
    print(DF)
    if Cond == False :
        break
    time.sleep(1)
#DataFrame.to_csv('DataFrame.csv', index=False) 
S6.close()
```